# Asp net mvc submit button not doing anything

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm trying to save an operation (Virement/Transfer, deposit, payment, etc). Operation Entity has a lot of properties. For every operation like transfer I have to choose only the matching properties for transfer, but the submit action doesn't do any thing. What is wrong?

OpérationController:

```
public ActionResult CreateVS()
    {
        PopulateClientsDropDownList();
        PopulateUtilisateursDropDownList();
        PopulateComptesDropDownList();
        PopulateTypeOpérationsDropDownList();
        PopulateCatégorieOpérationsDropDownList();
        PopulateDevisesDropDownList();
        PopulateMvtCaissesDropDownList();
        PopulateModePaiementsDropDownList();
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateVS(
      [Bind(Include = "OpérationId,TypeOpérationId,CatégorieOpération,RIBCrediteur,RIBDébiteur,IdClient,CompteId,CléRIB,NomExpéditeur,NomBeneficiare,Date,EtatValidation,Référence,Montant,Signe,Agent,DeviseId,ModePaiementId")]
 Opération a)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                service.CreateOpération(a);
                service.SaveOpération();
                return RedirectToAction("VSEffectué");
               // return Content("virement réussi");
            }
        }
        catch (RetryLimitExceededException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incapable d'enregistrer les modifications.Contacter l'Admin si le probléme persist.");
        }
        PopulateClientsDropDownList(a.OpérationId);
        PopulateComptesDropDownList(a.CompteId);
        PopulateTypeOpérationsDropDownList(a.TypeOpérationId);
        PopulateCatégorieOpérationsDropDownList(a.CatégorieOpérationId);
        PopulateDevisesDropDownList(a.DeviseId);
        PopulateMvtCaissesDropDownList(a.MvtCaisseId);
        PopulateModePaiementsDropDownList(a.ModePaiementId);
        return View(a);
    }
```

View:

```
    @model BankExpress.Domain.Entities.Opération
    @{ViewBag.Title = "CreateVS";}
    @using (Html.BeginForm(""CreateVS", "Opération"")) 
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr /><br />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeOpérationId, "Type Opération", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownList("TypeOpérationId", null, "Saisi Type Opération", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeOpérationId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CatégorieOpérationId, "Catégorie Opération", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownList("CatégorieOpérationId", null, "Saisi Catégorie Opération", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CatégorieOpérationId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RIBCrediteur, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RIBCrediteur, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RIBCrediteur, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RIBDébiteur, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RIBDébiteur, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RIBDébiteur, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdClient, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdClient, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdClient, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompteId, "N°Compte", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownList("CompteId", null, "Saisi N°Compte", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompteId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CléRIB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CléRIB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CléRIB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomExpéditeur, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomExpéditeur, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomExpéditeur, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomBeneficiare, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomBeneficiare, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomBeneficiare, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EtatValidation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.EtatValidation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EtatValidation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Montant, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Montant, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Montant, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Signe, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Signe, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Signe, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Agent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Agent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Agent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeviseId, "Devise", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownList("DeviseId", null, "Saisi Devise", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeviseId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModePaiementId, "Mode Paiement", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownList("ModePaiementId", null, "Saisi Mode Paiement", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModePaiementId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Valider" name="CreateVS"  class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Annuler", "Index", "Opération", new { @class = "col-md-pull-2  btn btn-primary" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra quotes in the beginform:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(""CreateVS", "Opération""))
```

Should be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateVS", "Opération"))
```

Comment: Is the submit at least getting to the controller? Or nothing at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AnswerView", "DarulIftah", FormMethod.Post))
```